# Plotting x and y axis in a JavaScript generated chart with Flot library?

Tags: javascript, plot, flot

I'm using flot library and I found from the docs that I can send a json object with any option I can right at the charting call.

So let's say I call:

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [ [] ], { yaxis: { show: true, max: 100, min: -100 }, xaxis: { show: true, max: 100, min: -100} });
```

However this is what I get as result (with a non empty data argument):

[image: Obtained plot]

But I don't want vertical lines marked at every axis tick, **but two lines corresponding to the axis.**

I don't want ending with the `x=0` and `y=0` plots. I would even have to obtains points arrays for it. How can I do this with flot or is there any recommended library to plot x,y points series with not much thrills.

Comment: What version of Flot are you using?  Could you clarify what you're looking for?  It's a little difficult to understand at the moment.

Comment: I'm using 0.8.3-alpha version and what I want is the lines corresponding to the axis being ploted, or, in other words, the `y=0` and `x=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get lines on the axes, add this to your options object:

```
grid: { markings: [{ xaxis: { from: 0.0, to: 0.0 }, color: 'black', lineWidth: 1 },
      { yaxis: { from: 0.0, to: 0.0 }, color: 'black', lineWidth: 1 }] };
```

If the other lines are still present after adding this, please provide a more complete example (e.g. a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)).